# Redirect old domain to new domain plus subpage

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted to redirect old domain to a new domain with a subpage

example: olddomain.com redirect to newdomain.com/subpage

here is what I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/newdomain\.com\/subpage\/" [R=301,L]
```

but it's redirecting to the newdomain.com instead of newdomain.com/subpage

Comment: Do you mean `olddomain.com` is redirecting to `newdomain.com/` instead of `newdomain.com/subpage/` ?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: Your rule already does that. Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using mod_rewrite, because this could be done simpler within the config of your olddomain:

```
Redirect permanent / http://newdomain.com/subpage/
```